# How do I get rid of the white box coming with my chart?

Tags: css

I have created a chart in visualforce and I am embedding it on a wordpress site. However it is coming with a white box which I am trying to either get rid of or style it appropriately. How can I do that?

Here is the visualforce code.
I have also attached the chart.
[image]

```
 <apex:chart height="300" width="330" data="{!pieData}" colorSet="#405395, #009345">
        <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name">
            <apex:chartLabel display="middle" orientation="vertical" font="bold 14px Helvetica" color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <apex:chartTips height="20" width="110"/>
        </apex:pieSeries>
        
    </apex:chart>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The white box is basically appearing because your image background is not transparent. Make sure that while exporting your image you are selecting a PNG format to make the background of the image transparent. You can also visit lunapic.com & use their transparent tool to make the background of your image transparent by simply uploading the image file there.

Comment: Its not an image but you have given me an idea. Thank you.